# Gridview List of objects with more objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

EXAMPLE:

```
public class Siniestro
    {

        public string Id_Siniestro { get; set; }
        public Liquidador liquidador { get; set; }

        public Siniestro()
        {

        }
    }

          Siniestro sin = new Siniestro()
            {
                Id_Siniestro = "1s",
                liquidador = new Liquidador()
                {
                    Id_liquidador = "1l"
                }
            };

List<Siniestro> lista = new List<Siniestro>();
list.Add(sin);
GridView.DataSource = lista;
GridView.DataBind();
```

grid Only show me id from object Siniestro..
and I want show id from Liquidador too.
how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

try this way, You have to call each field which you want to show in grid.

```
 List<Siniestro> list = new List<Siniestro>();
 list.Add(sin);
 GridView1.DataSource = list.Select(o=> new {o.Id_Siniestro,o.liquidador.Id_liquidador });
 GridView1.DataBind();
```